# C++ compiler independent DLLs using abstract interface

Tags: c++, dll, g++, abstract-class

I followed the guide at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach) and built a DLL with an abstract interface and exported the factory functions using the `extern "C"` command along with `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__cdecl` and by doing this the article claims that the DLL becomes compiler independent with a clean interface. However when using the DLL on two different versions of g++ the non-standard ABI created the standard c++ problems with DLL calling. In addition to the CodeProject article I also used an article from [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Exporting_a_class_from_a_DLL_for_multiple_instantiations) in order to be able to create multiple instances of the class.

How is it then possible to make the DLL compiler independent? and if this is not possible, is it then possible to instantiate a class within a DLL and make the functions pure C but calling the C++ functions related to the instantiated class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reproduce exactly the example that was given there? And what was the failure? You have to consider that not only your class, but any other class like `std::string` can't be used directly. That said, I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel but use some kind of component framework like COM.

To answer your second part, consider this:

```
// internal class
struct X
{
    void jump();
};


// compiler-independent C interface
struct X;
struct X* x_alloc(void);
void x_jump(struct X* x, float height);
void x_free(struct X* x);
```

This works. I have no idea what exactly you tried and what didn't work for you, there's just not enough info to tell.